# How to prefix node names inside tikz graph environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, scoping, tikz-node

I have a graph with two chains like this:

```
\begin{document}
\tikz []
\graph [layered layout, components go right top aligned, nodes=draw]
{
  {[nodes={name prefix=cat1}]
    cat1 -> {100, 200 [>minimum layers=2]};
    200  -> {210, 300};
    300  -> {400, 420, 450};
  };
  {[nodes={name prefix=cat2}]
    cat2 -> 101 -> 102 -> 203 -> {204, 408};
  };
%  (cat2102) -> (cat1200);
};
\end{document}
```

In the last commented line I try to draw an edge between nodes on the two chains but tikz complains that the nodes are not in the graph. How can I accomplish this? You have to compile the above with luatex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the key `/tikz/graphs/name` to use a prefix for the nodes on a graph. But then there is a separator added after the prefix. The default of `/tikz/graphs/name separator` is a space.

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{layered}

\begin{document}
\tikz []
\graph [layered layout, components go right top aligned, nodes=draw]
{
  {[name=cat1]
    cat1 -> {100,200 [>minimum layers=2]};
    200  -> {210, 300};
    300  -> {400, 420, 450};
  };
  {[name=cat2]
    cat2 -> 101 ->102-> 203 -> {204, 408};
  };
  (cat2 102) -> (cat1 200);
};
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Remark: If you want to use a different `name separator` you have to change its value before you set the `name` key.